# extract serialized array to use for wp-query

Tags: php, wp-query, array

I use wp-query and I need to display posts by author, using author id.

This is the serialized array:

```
a:19:{i:0;s:2:"89";i:3;s:3:"105";i:4;s:2:"74";i:5;s:3:"111";i:6;s:3:"167";i:7;s:2:"83";i:8;s:2:"54";i:9;s:2:"87";i:10;s:2:"85";i:11;s:2:"77";i:13;s:2:"82";i:14;s:2:"60";i:15;s:3:"149";i:16;s:3:"160";i:17;s:2:"71";i:18;s:1:"3";i:19;s:1:"2";i:20;s:3:"121";i:21;s:2:"57";}
```

This array includes the author's id so my question how can use wp-query 'author' or 'author__in' by using a serialized array?

Like this:

```
$first_post_ids = get_posts( array(
    'fields'         => 'ids',
    'post_type'      => 'the_posts',
    'author__in'      => get_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'following_users', true)
));
```

Comment: What is `'post_type' => 'the_posts'`? The correct post type for normal posts is `post`. Have you registered a custom post type called `the_posts`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `unserialize()` if its serialized string.

In your case from what I understand you store the array in the user_meta so its serialize it when you store it. but it will unserialize it when you use the `get_user_meta` so you dont need to `unserialize()`

Your code seems fine.

```
$author_in = get_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'following_users', true);
$first_post_ids = get_posts( array(
    'fields'         => 'ids',
    'post_type'      => 'the_posts',
    'author__in'      => $author_in
));
```

Comment: Sorry it's not wokring i get a php error: Warning: unserialize() expects parameter 1 to be string, Hope you can help me.

Comment: `get_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'following_users', true)` This return you serialized string?

Comment: If you mean if i print it like this: echo get_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'following_users', true); it's print 'Array' if i add your code it's give me a php error.

Comment: So from where you got the serialized data? add this array to your question

Comment: I have a follow - unfollow users system each user has following_users meta when the user follows another user a serialized array is stored into the database like the array that I put in the question, so I need to get the posts of users that I follow, Hope you understand me.

Comment: Your code seems fine for what I see. Maybe you strore the authors id in the array key?